# Update Events Dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i have a couple of queries regarding the fullcalendar by arshaw..

1. when i select a particular stretch of dates and give an appropriate title as shown [here](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/selectable.html)
   i get the event rendered in the calendar.. but when i want to save the event (I'm using asp.net) ie say after the user clicks on a save button,the `title`,`startdate`,`end date` has to be written into the `events[{}]` of the script..for this im using 
   `response.write("script /script(with the tags of course)")` after the button click which doesnt work..  would anyone suggest a better or a simpler working way?
2. also how to disable the `selectable` property? eg only an admin can set the event and a user can only see the event and not edit it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can update fullcalendar event JavaScript object with Response.Write() method.

You should use ajax to save event on server side and update calendar on client side.
Do something like this

```
 function saveEvent() {

    var event = { startDate: $('#txtDate').val(), description: $('#txtDescription').val(), id: id }


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "../UserCalendarService.asmx/SaveEvent",
        data: "{'startDate': '" + event.startDate + "','description':'" + event.description + "','id':'" + event.id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            result = result.d;
            eventFound = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', result.id).length;
            if (eventFound == 1) {
                existingEvent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', result.id);
                existingEvent[0].title = result.title;
                existingEvent[0].start = result.start;
                existingEvent[0].editable = result.editable;
                existingEvent[0].allday = true;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', existingEvent[0]);
            }
            else {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: result.title,
                    start: result.start,
                    id: result.id,
                    editable: result.editable,
                    allday: true
                },
             false // make the event "stick"
            );
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            if (err.Message == 'SomeErrorMessage') {
                //handleError, redirect or popup message
            }
        }
    });

}
```

As for your second question, event object has editable property. It is true or false.
You can found more about it in proper [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Comment: thank you for replying!well i understood whats happening but could you also post the serverside code? ie the contents of .asmx file..

Comment: Its just a web service that returns a list of event objects (List<Event>) from server, noting special with it